# Get the first result from thread

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, return

I have a function that consist of a for loop which takes very long to process each element.

In this loop I only care if I found one result or none, it doesn't matter the order in which the loop is executed.

It only have to process all of the elements if no result is found.

My code looks something like this:

```
import random
from time import sleep

class Elements:
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id

    def analyze(self,result):
        sleep(random.random()/2)
        if result > 0.9:
            return True

    def get_result(self):
        sleep(random.random()/2)
        return random.random()

def long_process(element):
    result = element.get_result()
    print element.id,result
    if element.analyze(result) == True:
        return element, result
    results.append(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    elements = []
    for n in xrange(10):
        elements.append(Elements(n))

    results = []
    desired = None
    for element in elements:
        desired = long_process(element)
        if desired:
            break
    if desired:
        print desired
    else:
        print sorted(results,reverse=True)[0]
```

if the desired element in the elements is found it output this:

```
0 0.150771147344
1 0.510095601312
2 0.28908099464
3 0.410008760093
4 0.435872688389
5 0.960307534462
(<__main__.Elements instance at 0x02311AD0>, 0.9603075344618438)
```

If not it will out put this:

```
0 0.361404239639
1 0.207105823026
2 0.851923103243
3 0.720462633138
4 0.58273657804
5 0.380394809851
6 0.590615590942
7 0.130172801534
8 0.57736519194
9 0.597338819896
0.851923103243 # the best element
```

I'm trying to use multiprocessing Pool to process each element in a separate thread. But I'm not getting the desired effect.

Here's what I tried.

```
def long_process(element):
    result = element.get_result()
    print element.id,result, element.analyze(result)
    if element.analyze(result) == True:
        return element, result
    results.append(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # freeze_support()
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    results = []
    pool.imap_unordered(long_process,elements)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print sorted(results)[0]
```

Outputs:

```
0 0.257371095047 None
1 0.8533933601 None
2 0.74433029726 None
3 0.138217827732 None
5 1 True
6 0.961344251697 True
4 0.0664381718173 None
7 0.000891701766875 None
9 1 True
8 0.771957314202 None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/User/user/Documents/Python/threading_test.py", line 40, in <module>
    print sorted(results)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But this have two problems:

- It should've stopped in the 5th element, and return it.
- If no True was found it should've stored all the resuls in the results list.

It is indeed working in unordered order(id 2,3,5,6,4...), it's getting the result, but it's not stopping when the analyze is True (5 1 True),
And neither is appending the results to the results list.[IndexError]

I tried using Pool.apply_async, but I was not able to fetch the results too.

Comment: What is the expected output of the example you posted?

Comment: if any `element.analyze(result) == True` I expect the result be `element, result`
Else I expect to all results be stored in the results list. In the output case present it would be the element with id 5 and '1'

Answer (score 0):

It was kind of hard working with your code, so I made an example using `apply_async` with a really simple function:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
# habit, you can use a flag instead ...
from threading import Event
import sys

# tell everyone we're done
done = Event()
# aggregate results here
results = []
success = []
```

Each process returns a result, no matter what:

```
def is7(x):
    if x == 7:
        return (x, True, )
    return x
```

This is a callback applied on each result, used when the result from `apply_async` returns:

```
def handle_result(x):
    if type(x) is tuple:
        # a tuple is necessarily the result we want, so we're done here.
        done.set()
        # stop pool
        p.terimnate()
        success.append(x)
        return
    results.append(x)
```

This is where we iterate through the items (1000 of them) and apply the function `is7` on each. If any of them finds a solution, we immediately stop and notify

```
p = Pool()
def run_processes():
    for element in range(0, 1000):
        print "trying %s" % str(element)
        p.apply_async(func=is7, args=(element,), callback=handle_result)

    # wait for completion
    p.close()
    p.join()
# start dispatchig tasks to pool
run_processes()
if done.isSet():
    # result may contain more than one, if two success tasks were executed closely
    print "Found result: %s" % str(success)
else:
    print "No results found, here is the list: %s " % str(results)
```

**Notice**: There's no guarantee the loop will stop exactly at 7, it'll probably stop a few items after 7 since tasks are dispatched asynchronously.

Comment: Not quite there, I want all the threads to stop if any of them find the '7', return it to the main thread. If the 7 is not found it will keep adding then results to the results list and return the results at the end. It will not return the result list if the 7 is found.

Comment: you can simply remove whatever arrived after the '7' in the list. I find it hard to understand why though :). And everything stops once 7 is encountered, however, some tasks may be in progress when that happens.

Comment: Because I want the 7 or the list, not both. It takes a lot of time to compute every element and it's also counter intuitive to store things if you don't need them(if the 7 is found the list is meaningless) and it would take more effort to sort the list and find the 7 in it.

Comment: And currently your code is still processing all the elements even after finding the desired result.

Comment: @f.rodrigues - see edit, now successful results are in another list. For me, it stops right after finding 7 (at around 10). It does not go all the way to 1000.

Comment: It's running trough all the elements. Try putting a sleep(random()) at  is7(), and printing the 'x' there, you will see that it runs trough all the elements before calling handle_result. If the 7 is found in is7() it should quite any other thread.

Comment: Add `p.terminate` when handling the tuple. See edit :)

Comment: It's not terminating either. The callback is only called after it finishes processing all the element using the is7() function. Since the is7 is where the most work is done. I've updated my question with a better structure of what my problem is dealing.

Comment: @f.rodrigues The callback is called each time an element is finished. This means you only process as many items as processes available before it is called on the successful result (usually less) - and then it terminates. To me it terimnates almost immediately after 7. All tasks are created but never processed so it shouldn't affect runtime.